# django api call from view change time data from get

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view where when it call an api, it will save the result get from it.

But i want to be able to change the time get from Post method to like +30min or +1hr and save it.

In my case, there is a `starttime` and `endtime`. But there is only a field `time` given back. So i will save the `time` into `starttime` and `time`+30min/1hr save into `endtime`

How do i do it ?

**views**

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 201 and request.method == 'POST':
        data = r.json()
        print(data)

        # Create a schedule/Save to schedule table

        user = data['patientId']
        userId = MyUser.objects.get(userId=user)
        # time
        gettime = data['time']
        gettime_add = ???

        saveget_attrs2 = {
            "userId ": userId ,
            "starttime": data["time"],
            "date": data["date"],
        }
        saving2 = Schedule.objects.create(**saveget_attrs2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert datestring to a `datetime` object and then use a `timedelta`.

```
import datetime
...
gettime = data['time']
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(gettime, <format_string>)
# for example datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-01, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_time = date_obj + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Comment: Thank you. The comment help me understand it